# How to use unique statements in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'd like to know how to use the unique statement in verilog .

for example

```
if (in0) se1 = 2'b00;
else if (in1) se1 = 2'b00;
else if (in2) se1 = 2'b00;
else if (in3) se1 = 2'b00;
```

If in0 and in1 are true then in0 is selected.

```
unique if (in0) se1 = 2'b00;
else if (in1) se1 = 2'b00;
else if (in2) se1 = 2'b00;
else if (in3) se1 = 2'b00;
```

If in0, in1 are true then how is this handled?

Comment: check [link](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/procedure_ctrl1.html)

Comment: @Emman Sorry, I can't understand what exactly the example want to say

Answer (score 3):

The `unique` keyword added to an `if` or `case` statement does two things:

- It adds an assertion to make sure that only one branch condition is true. The assertion is checked during simulation or by formal tools to make sure that it's not possible for more than condition to be true.
- It tells synthesis tools to generate optimized logic with the assumption that only one branch condition can be true at a time.

If it turns out that both in0 and in1 are true, simulation will still take the first branch, but you will get an error message. The actual hardware will generate unpredictable results.

Comment: Then how do I avoid a priority encoder in if else tree in verilog?

Comment: @nashile emman suggested you have a look at this [link](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/procedure_ctrl1.html) which discusses `unique` and `priority`. `priority` would appear the way to imply a priority encoding using case statements. `if` s are inherently priority based as the first match is evaluated and you do not hit the next `else if`

Comment: Thanks dave_59, BTW how to do to avoid the unpredictable results? just not use the unique? If yes, how to design in this situation about both in0 and in1 are true?

Comment: If both in0 and in1 are true, and you don't want a priority encoder, how do you want your logic to respond? See http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2005Israel_SystemVerilog_UniquePriority.pdf

Answer (score 2):

First of all I want to tell you that unique feature is for system-verilog not for verilog.
The SystemVerilog unique keyword can be applied to an if…else statement to convey the same uniqueness properties. For a unique if statement, a simulator will generate a run-time warning if any of the following is false:

- If two or more of the if conditions are true at the same time.
- If all of the if conditions (including else if) are false, and there is no final else branch.

Comment: is this sure about not for verilog?\

Comment: Yes. This Unique and priority keyword both are for system verilog.This is basically for replacement of full case and parallel case in verilog. You can refer this paper. http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2005Israel_SystemVerilog_UniquePriority.pdf